# Chained Transformation Matrices not producing predicted result

Tags: python, transforms

I have a problem for a few days and I can't solve it =[[
I have a composite object of 4 parts and I'm trying to do the translation and rotation operations on it.
Each part of the object has a rotation and translation matrix (so I have 4 different rotations and translations).

**The steps are:**

1. Calculates the transpose of the rotation matrix;
2. Place all the objects in the origin (0,0,0);
3. Define "Origin to Geometry" for all objects;
4. Conversion of the transposed rotation matrix to Euler Angles;
5. Modify the position and rotation of objects with their translations and rotations;

Here is a part of my code:

```
for i in range (1, 5):
    print ("done " + str(i)) 
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["obj"+str(i)]
    obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active

    with open('info/info_' + a + '_00' + str(i-1) + '.txt', newline='') as inputfile:


        results = list(csv.reader(inputfile))

        r1 = results[4]
        r2 = results[5]
        r3 = results[6]
        t = results[8]

        r1 = [num.strip().split(" ") for num in r1]
        r2 = [num.strip().split(" ") for num in r2]
        r3 = [num.strip().split(" ") for num in r3]
        t = [num.strip().split(" ") for num in t]


        #with transposed matrix
        a11 = float(r1[0][0]) 
        a12 = float(r2[0][0])
        a13 = float(r3[0][0])
        a21 = float(r1[0][1])   
        a22 = float(r2[0][2])   
        a23 = float(r3[0][3])
        a31 = float(r1[0][4])
        a32 = float(r2[0][5])
        a33 = float(r3[0][6])
        t1 = float(t[0][0]) # value of x
        t2 = float(t[0][7]) # value of y
        t3 = float(t[0][8]) # value of z

        #http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846
        rot_x = atan2(a32,a33) # result in rad
        rot_y = atan2(-a31,sqrt(pow(a32,2)+pow(a33,2)))
        rot_z = atan2(a21,a11) # to degrees -> degrees(rot_z)   

        bpy.data.objects["obj" + str(i)].location = [0, 0, 0]   
        bpy.data.objects["obj" + str(i)].rotation_euler = [0, 0, 0] 
        bpy.data.objects["obj" + str(i)].rotation_euler = [-rot_x, rot_z, -rot_y] 
        bpy.data.objects["obj" + str(i)].location = [t1, -t3, t2]
```

PS: I change the sequence of rotation angles because blenders coordinate system is different

The result is is below. The strange is that the object are disconnected, which can not happen. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

I also have attached the camera image that I have and that I wish

[image]

I know that the difference is small but it can not continue my work with this.

[information about the matrix](http://www.filedropper.com/info_1)

[Blender file](http://www.filedropper.com/2904151900)

[Original file](http://www.filedropper.com/traintext)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does anyone know another method to perform the rotation / translation of an object in blender?

Comment: are object center, scale as the originals, are you sure the calculation is precise and should output the desired result

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I've already performed the operation with another software and the result is equal to the "expected"

Comment: [here is a page about using matrix for transformation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/mathutils.html?highlight=matrix#mathutils.Matrix) but i think you will get the same result, they seems to be shifted ti the right a little that's why i think the origin is off the center

Comment: you just find the transform matrix and assign it to `obj.matrix_world` , BTW are there any parenting relations between this objects (their transformation will be relative to the parent )

Comment: I do not know if I understand your question correctly, but there is a relation between the objects. With the given matrices they should be connected.

Comment: in blender one object can be child of the other (it moves in the space of the parent not the world space) and how did it go with the matrix ?

Comment: I got the matrix by another method, then I realize the calculation to find the Euler angles.
I have no idea if they are children of each other. I got the objects exploding an entire object and by setting the Origin to Geometry, that's it.

Comment: so did you try the matrix way ? (sorry i couldn't understand )

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen your answer. I will try to use Matrix.Rotation and Matrix.Translation when I get home and then I'll analyze the results.

Comment: after trying if the problem still persist ,please upload a working example file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23311/discussion-between-daniel-caye-and-chebhou).